# My AS3 game won't go to full screen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fullscreen

I'm making an AS3 platform game. I don't know why but it won't go to full screen...

Here's my code :

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent; 

    public class PlatformGame extends MovieClip {
        // movement constants
        static const gravity:Number = .004;

        // screen constants
        static const edgeDistance:Number = 100;

        // object arrays
        private var fixedObjects:Array;
        private var otherObjects:Array;

        // hero and enemies
        private var hero:Object;
        private var enemies:Array;

        // game state
        private var playerObjects:Array;
        private var gameScore:int;
        private var gameMode:String = "start";
        private var playerLives:int;
        private var lastTime:Number = 0;

        // start game
        public function startPlatformGame() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, startGame);
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
            playerObjects = new Array();
            gameScore = 0;
            gameMode = "play";
            playerLives = 3;
        }
```

Do you know what could be the problem ? (I've just put the begining if my code, if you think it's necessary that I put all my code, don't hesitate to tell me)

Answer (score 0):

Read this Adobe documentation:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html